# Python: What is Wrong with these two Functions?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, call

I came across a problem within my program that I'm writing. I've narrowed down the problem to these two functions. The problem occurs when you call the function enterPasswords, enter invalid data such as 'a', then break out of the passwordLength function by entering valid data such as 'hello'. I've left some print statements there to help you see the problem. I've tried adding returns, but the same problem still occurs.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated. If you could tell me why the problem is occurring, I'm sure I could fix it myself. Thanks.

```
    def passwordLength(password):
        if (len(password) < 4) or (len(password) > 15):
            print("Error from server: Your password must be at least four and at most fifteen characters long.")
            enterPasswords()


    def enterPasswords():
        password = input("Input password: ")
        passwordLength(password)
        print(password)
        password2 = input("Re-enter password: ")
        print(password, password2)


    enterPasswords()
```

Here is an image of my problem (What I'm wanting to know is, why isn't the program ending where I've highlighted, why does it carry on, and why is 'a' being printed towards the end?):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5bBW.png

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Can you post a sample dialog so we can see how it's going wrong? You've got some weird logic going on (e.g I can input an invalid password, then a valid one, then confirm the invalid one) but the program does run.

Comment: I've edited my post with a description and an image of the problem. Thanks for your reply by the way.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that if the user inputs an invalid password at first, it repeats `enterPasswords` - however, if the user completes this successfully, it goes back to the initial `enterPasswords`.  Instead, try

```
def passwordLength(password):
    if (len(password) < 4) or (len(password) > 15):
        print("Error from server: Your password must be at least four and at most fifteen characters long.")
        return False
    return True


def enterPasswords():
    password = input("Input password: ")
    while not passwordLength(password):
        password = input("Input password: ")

    print(password)
    password2 = input("Re-enter password: ")
    print(password, password2)
```

This will continue to ask the user to reinput the first password until it is valid, and only then it will ask the user to confirm.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have tried implementing my program in your way, in the past. I was just wondering why my way isn't working the way I want it.

Comment: @user2240694 As I mention in my post, and as the image you posted illustrated, your issue is coming from the fact that you call the `enterPasswords` function from `passwordLength`.  `enterPasswords` asks for the password twice - BUT, if it isn't valid, it goes to `passwordLength` which initiates another session of `enterPasswords`.  This causes the multiple prompts of re-entry.

So you can either
1. Do something similar to what I did and make `passwordLength` a completely independant function, removing the circular nature of your code
2. Break from `enterPasswords` if `passwordLength` is used

Comment: Oh I see, so because the enterPasswords function doesn't finish executing when invalid data gets inputted, the program will always go back to where it left off when valid data is entered. I do understand the problem now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The password variable in `passwordLength()` is completely unrelated to the variable in `enterPasswords()`. The behaviour might also not be as you expect it to be. Try something like this:

```
def passwordLength(pw):
    return 4 <= len(pw) <=15

def getPw():
    return input("Enter password: ")

def enterPasswords():
    pw = getPw()
    while not passwordLength(pw):
        print("Incorrect password length.")
        pw = getPw()

    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are calling each other in a bad way. If you try to follow line by line your algorithme (using the case you mentioned with 'a' and 'hello') you will probably see the problem.

Here is a solution :

```
def passwordLength(password):
    if (len(password) < 4) or (len(password) > 15):
        print("Error from server: Your password must be at least four and at most fifteen characters long.")
        return False
    else : return True    


def enterPasswords(): 
    passwordOK = False
    while not passwordOK :
        password = input("Input password: ")
        passwordOK = passwordLength(password)
    print(password)
    password2 = input("Re-enter password: ")
    print(password, password2)

enterPasswords()
```